# Crate JDBC driver load balancing issue

Tags: crate

**Q1.** I have a crate cluster of version 1.0.2 and I am using older version of crate JDBC driver to connect to it from java program. I have specified all nodes of crate in the JDBC driver URL by separating them with comma. When I fire queries from my java program to crate, I can see memory and CPU usage of only 1 crate node increases and this node is 1st in the comma separated list given in the connection URL. After some time, that node runs out of memory . Could someone please explain why this happens ?  I remember reading documentation of crate driver which indicated that crate driver load balances the queries across all specified client nodes. All my nodes are client enabled.

**Q2.** I tried same experiment with Crate 2.1.6 and JDBC driver 2.1.7 and I can see same behavior. I have verified that all the queries are getting fired on the data which is spread across multiple nodes. In latest documentation, I can see a new property got added viz loadBalanceHosts https://crate.io/docs/clients/jdbc/en/latest/connecting.html#jdbc-url-format

Right now I do not have this property added. Was this property present and required on JDBC driver version 2.1.7 ? Why do developer have to do worry about load balancing when crate cluster and JDBC drivers are supposed to provide that ?

FYI, most of my queries have group by clause  and I have few billions of records to experiment with. Memory configured is 30GB per node.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the lastest driver: https://github.com/crate/crate-jdbc/blob/master/docs/connecting.txt#L62

Comment: Thanks for reply Jodok. Link seems to be broken. Could you tell exact version JDBC driver where this is fixed? I will try with that.

Comment: Tested with JDBC driver version 2.3.0 and Crate 1.0.2. I still see only first node is getting all the load. :(

Comment: Link is broken, and also test with latest version its taking only first node